Unable to consume images from Directus with React
This is my API endpoint
https://comfy-store.directus.app/items/products/
which contains the data I need title, price, image
From react I can access title, price no problem but for image I am getting:
"{"errors":[{"message":"You don't have permission to access this.","extensions":{"code":"FORBIDDEN"}}]}"
<img
   src={"https://comfy-store.directus.app/items/assets/" + image}/> 

From another question on here I think I need to add an access token to the src to access the image.
Steps to use the Directus CMS API
Tried using the token from thread above:
https://comfy-store.directus.app/public/item/products?access_token=BGJFwQ1KlHnH91V2oIwMb34343G but get
{"errors":[{"message":"Invalid user credentials.","extensions":{"code":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS"}}]}

Can anyone tell me how I can get the access token from Directus I can't find it.
const ProductsGrid = () => {
    const { products } = useLoaderData();
    const data = products.data
   

    // const directusApi = 'https://comfy-store.directus.app/items/products/';
    // const fileId = image;
    // const accessToken = 'your-access-token';

    // const imageUrl = `${directusApi}/assets/${fileId}?access_token=${accessToken}`;
    // console.log(imageUrl);

    return (
        <div className='pt-12 grid gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 '>
            {data.map((product) => {
                const { title, description, image, price } = product;
                return (
                    <Link
                        key={product.id}
                        to={`/products/${product.id}`}
                        className='card w-full  shadow-xl hover:shadow-2xl transition duration-300 '
                    >
                        <figure className='px-4 pt-4'>
                            <img
                                src={"https://comfy-store.directus.app/items/assets/" + image}
                                alt={title}
                                className='rounded-xl h-64 md:h-48 w-full object-cover'
                            />
                        </figure>
                        <div className='card-body items-center text-center'>
                            <h2 className='card-title capitalize tracking-wider'>{title}</h2>
                            <span className='text-secondary'>${price}</span>

                        </div>
                    </Link>

                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
export default ProductsGrid; 


Got it working the correct src was 'https://comfy-store.directus.app/assets/1fc98727-3e83-436f-8e15-16783deed0e5'

From quickstart guide

Create and login to your Directus Cloud account
The very first time you log in to your Cloud Account, you will be
prompted to create a Team. Each Directus Cloud Project exists within
the scope of one Team. They allow you to organize Team Members,
Projects and Project Billing as desired.
Create a new project
Once started, it should take around 90 seconds for the Cloud Project
to created. During this time, a link will be sent to the email
associated with your Cloud Account. The email will contain your
Project URL as well as an email and password to login. If you used
GitHub to create your account, this will be your GitHub email.
Access your new project
Login to your new project using the URL in your email inbox or on your
Directus Cloud Dashboard.

After having an account access the dashboard and register a token
